# Django request.user become AnonymousUser after third party redirect

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ngrok

test.html:

```
<a href="https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?    ...">authorize</a>
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def myview(req):
    user = req.user

   return render(req, 'test.html')
```

For ebay's oauth process, you have to provide users with a link to ebay's server, which asks the user if they want to give credentials to you.  If they accept, ebay redirects the user to a given url with a querystring containing the access key.

The problem is, when I authorize my app with ebay, the user gets redirected to my login page (despite already being logged in).  If I remove the `@login_required` decorator, `req.user` returns AnonymousUser instead.  This is a problem since I don't know which user to assign the access token to.

What am I missing here?

**Note** that I am using ngrok to tunnel my server, and I have no problems
rendering `myview` other than the fact that the user is Anonymous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that when I logged the user in initially, I was using the domain `localhost:8000` instead of my ngrok instance.

Logging my user in using my ngrok address fixed the problem.

Comment: Sidebar, but you can easily and programmatically manage `ngrok` from Python application using `pyngrok`. Django example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), which also shows how to update URL, webhooks, etc. when the dev server boots.